# VUE - QUASAR - TIPTAP - How to Set CSS Height on Editor's Inner Element

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar-framework, tiptap

How can I get the inner editor portion (which is highlighted with a thin blue line) to go full height. This is the internal element that gets created by the tiptap editor:

```
<div contenteditable="true" tabindex="0" class="ProseMirror" spellcheck="false"> Editable content goes here./div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I manually added the classes ('col' and 'column') in the rendered output and now it works the way I want it to. Is there a way to do this without having to reach into the class property of the element?

```
<div contenteditable="true" tabindex="0" class="ProseMirror col column" spellcheck="false"> Content Here </div>
```

Here is the component code I am using in my quasar example app. I have tried umpteen different variations of classes in the divs around the editor. Nothing I do seems to affect the resulting "contenteditable" div container above.

```
<template>
  <q-page class="column justify-start">
      <div class="column col absolute-full bg-secondary">
        <div class="col column editor">
          <editor-menu-bar :editor="editor" v-slot="{ commands, isActive }">
            <div class="menubar">

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.bold() }"
                @click="commands.bold"
              >
                <icon name="bold" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.italic() }"
                @click="commands.italic"
              >
                <icon name="italic" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.strike() }"
                @click="commands.strike"
              >
                <icon name="strike" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.underline() }"
                @click="commands.underline"
              >
                <icon name="underline" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.code() }"
                @click="commands.code"
              >
                <icon name="code" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.paragraph() }"
                @click="commands.paragraph"
              >
                <icon name="paragraph" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.heading({ level: 1 }) }"
                @click="commands.heading({ level: 1 })"
              >
                H1
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.heading({ level: 2 }) }"
                @click="commands.heading({ level: 2 })"
              >
                H2
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.heading({ level: 3 }) }"
                @click="commands.heading({ level: 3 })"
              >
                H3
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.bullet_list() }"
                @click="commands.bullet_list"
              >
                <icon name="ul" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.ordered_list() }"
                @click="commands.ordered_list"
              >
                <icon name="ol" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.blockquote() }"
                @click="commands.blockquote"
              >
                <icon name="quote" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.code_block() }"
                @click="commands.code_block"
              >
                <icon name="code" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                @click="commands.horizontal_rule"
              >
                <icon name="hr" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                @click="commands.undo"
              >
                <icon name="undo" />
              </button>

              <button
                class="menubar__button"
                @click="commands.redo"
              >
                <icon name="redo" />
              </button>

            </div>
          </editor-menu-bar>
          <editor-content class="col column editor__content" :editor="editor" />
        </div>
      </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import Icon from 'components/Icon'
import { Editor, EditorContent, EditorMenuBar } from 'tiptap'
import {
  Blockquote,
  CodeBlock,
  HardBreak,
  Heading,
  HorizontalRule,
  OrderedList,
  BulletList,
  ListItem,
  TodoItem,
  TodoList,
  Bold,
  Code,
  Italic,
  Link,
  Strike,
  Underline,
  History
} from 'tiptap-extensions'

export default {
  components: {
    EditorContent,
    EditorMenuBar,
    Icon
  },
  data () {
    return {
      editor: new Editor({
        extensions: [
          new Blockquote(),
          new BulletList(),
          new CodeBlock(),
          new HardBreak(),
          new Heading({ levels: [1, 2, 3] }),
          new HorizontalRule(),
          new ListItem(),
          new OrderedList(),
          new TodoItem(),
          new TodoList(),
          new Link(),
          new Bold(),
          new Code(),
          new Italic(),
          new Strike(),
          new Underline(),
          new History()
        ],
        content: `
          <h2>
            Hi there,
          </h2>
          <p>
            this is a very <em>basic</em> example of tiptap.
          </p>
          <pre><code>body { display: none; }</code></pre>
          <ul>
            <li>
              A regular list
            </li>
            <li>
              With regular items
            </li>
          </ul>
          <blockquote>
            It's amazing 
            <br />
            – mom
          </blockquote>
        `
      })
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    this.editor.destroy()
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I have been learning about Vue.js & Quasar UI toolset. I want to use the TIPTAP WYSIWYG editor component (available here: https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap). I am fine with their examples, I can get the component to load and work fine. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get the inner editing part (which gets outlined in blue when you click on it) to go 'Full Height' from the outset.

I have tried everything I can think of and searched and searched for some sort of example. The editor expands (grows) fine when you add content, but for some reason, I can't get it to start at full height-- which I'll note the example doesn't illustrate either.

What am I not doing?

Answer (score 9):

Try writing this on css

```css
/* remove outline */
.ProseMirror:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/* set */
.ProseMirror {        
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```